# Excel - reference to a last non-empty row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to make Excel find the cells from the last non-empty row, containing a certain character. I am attaching the picture and further explanation below:

[image]

So, DK3 value is 4, DL3 value is 4, DM3 value is 6 and DN3 value is 5.
All I need now is DK5 to display the first value from a range containing at least one character from DK3, and the second one with the same character to be displayed in DK6, and so on. Same for DL3, DM3 and DN3.

The range for reference, however, should be AV:BW, but the last non-empty row.

How is this possible, please.

Comment: Only the helper column:  =IF(OR(MID(AW6,1,1)=$DK$3,MID(AW6,2,1)=$DK$3),AW6,""), which means I need 4 of those helper columns per each row. Now I have a different direction of the spreadsheet development,(although it may be enough, still would have been nice to have something useful as described originally in my arsenal).

Comment: You should describe that in the [original question](http://superuser.com/posts/1047674/edit) and what's happening and how it's different from your intended outcome.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still thinking if I could find the better solution for my task. I will revert.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a few manually-calculated expected results to your post to help clarify.

Comment: It is not 100% clear for me what you want to do. If you want to get the second character out of a cell, easiest way is to use `=MID(<cell or text>;<start from>;<nr of characters>)`. For example to get the second character from DK3 would be `=MID(DK3;2;1)`

Comment: Fro the last row of the table (AV:BW) I wanted simply to find the cells that contain The values in DK3:DN3 (should be at least one character's match). The key is to use the LAST non-empty Row as a reference. So far I managed to find all Rows. Its not the same...

Comment: @SKYTTEN - are you okay with using VBA?

Comment: I am very new to VBA, but still would not mind having that option.